# Executing Password Change over Ruby Net-SSH

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I am looking to execute a password change over Net-ssh and this code seems to hang:

```
Net::SSH.start(server_ip, "user", :verbose => :debug ) do |session|

  session.process.popen3("ls") do |input, output, error|

    ["old_pass","test", "test"].each do |x|

        input.puts x

    end

  end

end
```

I know the connection works because using a simple exec I can get the output from ls on the remote server, but this hangs.

Any ideas?

The last message from debug is that the public key succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will solve your issue ,, note this script to change password for a list of servers list in file

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Change  Password is a simple script to change the password for a list of servers 
# Coded by : Sabry Saleh
# License : GPL2
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#=-Notes-=
# You have to install ruby + net-ssh gems 
# sudo gem install net-ssh
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

require 'net/ssh'

host = IO.readlines('test1.txt') # full path of servers' list
port = 22       # SSH port
user = 'username'   # username
  i  = 0

while i < host.length 

  Net::SSH.start(host[i], user , :password => "User pass" , :port=> port) do |ssh|
    ssh.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.on_request "exit-status" do |channel, data|
      $exit_status = data.read_long
    end
      channel.request_pty do |channel, success| 
      channel.exec("sudo passwd UserName")  # Logged user shuold be root or sudoers memeber
      if success
        channel.on_data do |channel, data|
          puts data.inspect.chomp("\r\n")
          channel.send_data("New pass\n") # put the New password you need to set
          sleep 0.1
        end
      else
        puts "FAILED!!"
      end
    end
    channel.wait
    puts "SUCCESS!!" if $exit_status == 0
    end
  end
i += 1
end
```